# Django print Users list

Tags: python, django

I want to print list of users, but i'm not sure how to do it. I have already 2 registered users but they are not printed

mainapp\templates\home.html

```html
<!-- templates/home.html-->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <p>Hi {{ user.username }} | <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>

    <ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'mainapp:lista' user.id %}">{{ user.username}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
  </br>
  <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">sign up</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

mainapp\views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Osoba
from django.template import loader
from django.views.generic import View, ListView, DetailView
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def lista(request):
    users = User.objects.order_by('-username')[:5]
    return render(request, 'mainapp/home.html', {'users': users})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you constructed your template already, so instead of using `HttpResponse(output)`, we can use [**`render`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render

def lista(request):
    users = User.objects.order_by('-username')[:5]
    return render(request, 'mainapp/home.html', {'users': users})
```

Here we thus pass a variable named `users` to the template and it carries the value of the `users` local variable in your `lista` function.

You usually store your template in a directory with the same name as the app in the `template` directory of the app, like:

```
mainapp
    templates
        mainapp
            home.html
    __init__.py
    apps.py
    urls.py
    models.py
    views.py
```

Comment: I changed already HttpResponse to render but i don't understand what to do next. Is it problem if i store template in mainapp/templates/home.html?

Comment: @BillCosby: not per se, but then the template name is `'home.html'`, and the problem is that this can easly result in different apps having the same template names, and thus some problem can arise that you render a template with the same name from another app.

Comment: I wont use  the same names. This is a little voting app. What about printing users? Do you have more tips?

Comment: @BillCosby: well you print the users in the template you shared in the question.

Comment: But it doesnt work. That's showing me as i wont have any Users registered. I have already 2 users

Comment: @BillCosby: it shows: `<p>No polls are available.</p>`? Can you see the users in the database?

Comment: Yes :x :x :x :x :x

Comment: @BillCosby: can you inspect the `auth_user` table in the database?

Comment: How to do that? Im really beginner

Comment: When im writing in console `print(User.objects.all())` it is showing me my users

Comment: @BillCosby: (a) did you restart the server? (b) are you sure you are rendering the template here (c) do you use `{% if users %}` as a check (so with `if users`, not some other variable?

Comment: (a) yes (b) yes, im sure, because the rest of code is working in this template (c) i removed it and now its look like this
`<ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'mainapp:lista' user.id %}">{{ user.username}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>`

Comment: @BillCosby: it is really strange that it just emits the template code. You did not write `HttpResponse(..)` in the view?

Comment: I just edited my post. Look up. There are full files view.py and home.html

Answer (score 1):

in **views.py**

```
class UserList(ListView):
    model = User

class UserDetail (DetailView):
    model = User
```

in **urls.py**

```
path ('detail/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view(), name="user-detail"),
path ('detail/<int:pk>/', views.UserList.as_view(), name="user-list"),
```

in **user_list.html**

```
{% if object_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for object in object_list %}
        <li><a href="{% 'url user-detail' object.id %}">{{ object.username}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul> {% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p> 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I did it but it is still printing: 'No polls are available'. I have 2 users added already